# Quantity value not updating in the database when I add a product that already exists in the table

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have a 'shopping_cart' table which holds all products ordered by users. This table has a 'quantity' column which holds the number of times a user has added a certain product in their cart. If the user clicks 'Add to Cart' button the second time on the same product, the new quantity value should be the old one + 1. For some reason (pretty silly one I assume), this whole logic doesn't work. The quantity remains 1 all the time.

So, I have a list of products, each products has a button 'Add to Cart', that when clicked, it sends a request to a CartController servlet, which calls the addToCart() method from a CartDAO which accesses the database and inserts the product. In the CartDAO file, the method addToCart() is a boolean which returns True if the product was inserted, or False if it already exists in the table. As you can see from the code below, the first 'if' checks if rows have been updated, and if they weren't(meaning the products already exists and the query returned an error), it enters the 'else' statement which should theoretically return only the row from the table containing the added product, then obtain the 'quantity' value from that row's quantity column, then update it with +1. For some reason, this doesn't happen. I've checked all the queries and I am 100% sure they have a valid syntax, I also know that the products are indeed added to the cart, so the logic of the addToCart method works, partially. I've read the javadocs for the ResultSet object and according to that, everything should work fine, as I am pointing the cursor to the first row of the resultSet, which only contains one row anyway. Help

This is the post method of the CartController servlet that is accessed when a product is added to the cart(sorry for the lack of syntax highlighting, I have no idea how to do that):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Integer productID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productID"));
        String fk_username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
        String productName = request.getParameter("productName");
        String productPrice = request.getParameter("productPrice");
        Integer productPriceSup = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productPriceSup"));
        String productImage = request.getParameter("productImage");

        if(dao.addToCart(productID, fk_username, productName, productPrice, productPriceSup, productImage)) {       
            response.sendRedirect("processors.jsp");
        }else {
            String error3 ="Please try again later";
            request.setAttribute("error3", error3);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("processors.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }           
    }
```

This is the CartDAO code that is related to the problem:

```
public class CartDAO {
    String sql ="insert into shopping_cart(P_ID, fk_uname, P_name, P_price, P_price_sup, P_image, quantity) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WebApp?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    String username="jipa";
    String password="";
    private Statement statement = null;
    private Statement statement2 = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;
    private int quantity=1;

    public boolean addToCart(Integer productID, String fk_username, String productName, String productPrice, Integer productPriceSup, String productImage){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            PreparedStatement pstatement= connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstatement.setInt(1, productID);
            pstatement.setString(2, fk_username);
            pstatement.setString(3, productName);
            pstatement.setString(4, productPrice);
            pstatement.setInt(5, productPriceSup);
            pstatement.setString(6, productImage);
            pstatement.setInt(7,  quantity);
            if(pstatement.executeUpdate()>0) {
                return true;

            }else {
                String getProduct ="select * from shopping_cart where fk_uname="+"\""+fk_username+"\""+" AND P_ID="+"\""+productID+"\"";
                statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); 
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(getProduct);
                resultSet.absolute(1);
                quantity=(resultSet.getInt("quantity")+1);
                String addQuantity ="update shopping_cart set quantity="+"\""+quantity+"\""+" where P_ID="+"\""+productID+"\""+" AND fk_uname="+"\""+fk_username+"\"";
                statement2 = connection.createStatement(); 
                statement2.executeQuery(addQuantity);
                return true;
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;   

    }
```

The code has no errors, it runs just fine. If I omitted some important detail, please let me know so I can update the question.

Comment: Just wait until you discover INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY... It will blow your mind

Comment: wow... it actually worked. Spent so much time trying to come up with a stupid algorithm for this and now I did it with just 3 words. Can you post this as an answer so I can award it as the correct answer?

Comment: It's just a FAQ. But feel free to accept your own answer, or otherwise delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

As Strawberry said, the solution is to get rid of the whole 'else' statement and replace the initial insert statement with this:

```
String sql ="insert into shopping_cart(P_ID, fk_uname, P_name, P_price, P_price_sup, P_image, quantity) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=quantity+1;";
```